# how to use adodb activerecord and orm together

Tags: php, activerecord, model, adodb

in my project i want to use [adodb](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm) orm and [adodb activerecord](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-active-record.htm) together.
i want adodb ORM in $db property and activerecord in $ar property that i use both of them in my class.

this is main Model class :

```
class Model {

        public $ar ;

        public $db;

    function __construct() {
        include('Model/adodb/adodb.inc.php');
        $this->db = ADONewConnection($driver);
        $this->db->Connect($server , $username , $password , $database) ;

        include('Model/adodb/adodb-active-record.inc.php');
        $ar = NewADOConnection("$driver://$username:$password@$server/$database");
        $thid->ar = ADOdb_Active_Record::SetDatabaseAdapter($ar);
     }
}
```

and Posts table class :

```
<?php
class Posts extends Model
{
   function getRows()
   {
         $re = $this->db->Execute('SELECT * From posts')    ;
         return $re->GetRows();
   }

   function getTitle()
   {
         $this->ar->load('id = 5');
         return $this->ar->title;
   }
}
```

in the Posts class function getRows right work but function getTitle not work.

how can i use both of them in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find answer.
for this i create new class then extends from Adodb_activeRecord :

```
class Model_ActiveRecord extends ADOdb_Active_Record
{
    function __construct($table = false, $pkeyarr = false, $db = false)
        {
            parent::__construct($table, $pkeyarr, $db);
        }
}
```

then in my constructor model :

```
$this->ar = new Model_ActiveRecord('posts');
```